# After upgrading to ruby 2.5.1 the rails server failing with "warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

All,

After upgrading my Ruby to 2.5.1 and Rails version to 4.2.5, when I try to start my rails server I get the following message below and it crashes. I've seen a couple of links about the error, but those didn't prevent the rails server from starting up. Is there another way besides upgrading to 5.0.2?  Also my Gem version is 2.7.6.

```
rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Use an earlier ruby version? I'm on rails 4.2.7.1 with ruby 2.3.1 and all is fine. Or, according to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27670), upgrade to 4.2.8 or higher.

Comment: That worked @jvillian thank you.  I upgraded to Rails 4.2.8!  Can you post this as an answer in case someone else has the same issue possibly?  I'll accept it as an answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using an earlier version of ruby. I'm on rails 4.2.7.1 with ruby 2.3.1 and all is fine.

Alternatively, and according to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27670) issue on Github, you can upgrade to rails 4.2.8 or higher for ruby 2.4 (and presumably higher) support.